# Undefined property: stdClass::$Unblinking Eternity

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a list of my items from the Steam service. I have two functions, 1 of them: receives all items from the Steam store, 2 functions receive the price, name, picture of the item. So, when I try to parse the data, in one of my account I get an error: `Undefined property: stdClass::$Unblinking Eternity`, and in my second account all parsing good.

`var_dump($items); exit;` show me:

```
object(stdClass)#547 (34183) { ["Orb of Deliverance"]=> object(stdClass)#546 (2) 
{ ["price"]=> float(58.31) ["appid"]=> string(3) "570" } ["Planks of the Bogatyr"]=> object(stdClass)#54.......
```

and some logs:

```
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined property: stdClass::$Unblinking Eternity', '/var/app/Http/Controllers/InventoryController.php', '320', array('market_hash_name' => 'Unblinking Eternity', 'json' => '{"Orb of Deliverance":{"price":57.780000000000001,"appid":"570","count":427,"bprice":51.490000000000002,"bcount":11663},"Planks of the Bogatyr":{"price":0.14000000000000001,"appid":"570","count":922,"bprice":0.12,"bcount":859},"Headdress of the Ember Crane":{"price":0.16,"appid":"570","count":808,"bprice":0.14999999999999999,"bcount":218},"Sash of Divine Ascension":
```

Error show at 320 line, 320 line its: `if($items->$item_name == 'undefined'){`

My 2 functions:

```
public static function getItemPrice($market_hash_name) {
    try {
        if(\Cache::has('prices')){
            $json = \Cache::get('prices');
            $items = json_decode($json);
            $item_name = $market_hash_name;
            if($items->$item_name == 'undefined'){
                return false;
            } else{
                return $items->$item_name->price;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch(Exception $e){
        return false;
    }
}

public function getPriceItems()
{
    $data = file_get_contents("http://steamp.ru/v2/?key=key");
    if(!$data) return 'Error getting data';
    $data = json_decode($data);
    if(!isset($data->success)) return 'Error getting data';
    if($data->success && isset($data->items)){
        \Cache::put('prices', json_encode($data->items), 44640);
        return 'Successfully Parsing';
    } else if(isset($data->message)){
        return $data->message;
    }
    return 'Error getting data';
}
```

How i understand, a problem with `stdClass`.

Where my mistake? How i can fix this error?

Comment: It seems to be explicit, the property `Unblinking Eternity` doesn't exist in your object `$items`. In the debug info you give, i can see it's only value of `market_hash_name`.

Comment: It may be handier to decode to arrays if you're going to have to deal with difficult to reference object properties. Just a thought.

Comment: As pointed out, you may be better off using arrays as there are fewer problems with names containing spaces. (just add `true` as in `json_decode($data, true)`)

Comment: @Nigel I don't think that's really the root cause of this problem, though. I think it's `if($items->$item_name == 'undefined'){` rather than using isset

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I've re-opened it, perhaps need OP to respond and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: if i make `$items = json_decode($json, true);`, i received `Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `if ($items->$item_name == 'undefined') {` you're referring to a dynamic property name without checking that it exists first.

You can check that using `isset()`.

```
if (!isset($items->$item_name) || $items->$item_name == 'undefined') {
```

I don't know if the item really will ever be the string 'undefined', though, so you *might* be able to do away with that part altogether.

```
if (!isset($items->$item_name)) {
```

Comment: i think your first method `if (!isset($items->$item_name) || $items->$item_name == 'undefined') {` work, because now page load too slow (i think that parse) and i received 504 bad gateway error :P and now need to check server settings :D

Comment: but can you tell me such a thing, how to increase the parsing speed? Ie 100 itens are parsing for me about 30 seconds, more items  - more time